How to correctly map task ids in Dynamic Task Mapping feature Airflow?
I use Airflow 2.9 and I have created two tasks with PythonOperator. The first task calls python function an generates list of task names. Then the list passed to the next task which generates tasks with Dynamic Task Mapping feature.
    def get_task_names():
        task_list = [['task_1'], ['task_2'], ['task_3']]
        return task_list

    def generate_tasks(task_name):
        time.sleep(10)

    get_task_names = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'get_task_names',
        python_callable = get_task_names
    )

    generate_tasks = PythonOperator.partial(
        task_id = 'generate_tasks',
        python_callable = generate_tasks,
        map_index_template="{{ task.op_args[0] }}"
    ).expand(op_args=get_task_names.output)

    get_task_names >> generate_tasks

Everything works fine but the task names are not mapped while it's running:

The task names map fine only when task is finished:

Is it possible to make it all mapped while the tasks are running?

Hey Andrey, were you able to find the solution to this? Also what package did you import to get map_index_template to work?

There is an open Airflow ticket for this issue Rendering custom map index before task is run. #39118
